# Where is Rails actually writing the Set-Cookie header for _session_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, session-cookies

Initial `GET` requests to my Rails 4 app will usually respond with a `Set-Cookie` Header for `_session_id`. Now I would like to ensure this header for some `POST` requests, but am not yet proficient enough with all the middlewares to pinpoint the exact location of where the header is being set.

Could anybody help with that, and maybe the transfer into a custom controller?

Meanwhile I will further investigate `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what You are looking for is actually this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Response/set_cookie

The response should set the cookie header . You can do this in a middleware or a after_action filter în your base controller.

Personally i prefer using the filter for this case.